# Nested for loops are too slow in all situations?

Tags: matlab, optimization, floating-point, time-complexity, numeric

I'm coding numeric methos of undergradute course in Matlab and I looked that codes that use a lot of nest for loops are too slowly instead codes with a lot of floating point operations (add, multiply, etc). Does anyone know if exist a paper or study about this fact (nest for loops are slow). I undestand that in most of times this depend of how optimiced is the code but, in genereally is true?. In Google, I couldn't find any paper about this fact.

I have this code in matlab

```
function [L,operaciones]=CholeskyInc(A)
tic
[n,m]=size(A);
operaciones = 0;
if n~= m; error('A no es cuadrada');
else
    L=speye(n,n);
    for k=1:n
       L(k,k)=sqrt(A(k,k));
       for i=k+1:n
           if A(i,k)~=0
               L(i,k)=A(i,k)/A(k,k);
           end
       end
       for j=k+1:n
           for i=j:n
               if (A(i,j))~=0
                   L(i,j)=A(i,j)-A(i,k)*A(j,k);
               end
           end
       end
    end
    L = tril(A);
toc
end
```

For large matrix (for example 625x625) this code takes more than 2 minutes in compute the matrix but it's appear to be a simple code

Comment: I doubt that you can generalize that statement. This might have come from a time when Matlab did not Just-In-Time compile their loops. Anyways, the question is off-topic. It may be on-topic if you have a specific example which you benchmarked for various implementations ...

Comment: Ok, I update the question with my code

Comment: It looks like you are random-accessing a sparse matrix. This is never really efficient. If `A` is not sparse, you could leave out the `if(A(...)~=0` to see how much faster this gets. Also, at the end of the code, you overwrite the computations in the loops by `L = tril(A)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if exist a paper or study about this fact (nest for loops are slow).

There is no general principle that nested loops are too slow.

You might have seen some advice that accessing arrays column-wise (when they are stored in row-major order) is slow. This is due to hardware design that accesses neighboring elements quickly (because they are fetched from memory in groups and held in high-speed cache) while accessing multiple widely separated elements is slow. I bring this up as a vague match to your question. There are numerous other issues about algorithms and about hardware that contribute to inefficiency or efficiency.

Comment: Yes, in first programming course my professor said something related with this. Do you know where can I find more info about this fact? I suppose that in books of design of computers but I'm not sure